# URL key not generating during product import

Tags: magento-1.9, import, url-key

I am importing products through a `CSV` file from admin.
I have checked the `CSV` file, it contains `_product_websites` column with value "base".

But still URL keys are not generating after import.
Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After running the import you need to re-index the `Catalog URL Rewrites`  index. This will generate URL's for your products.

You can do so through the admin panel:

> Admin Panel -> System -> Index Management -> Next to `Catalog URL Rewrites` Click `Reindex Data`

You can also reindex through a `SSH` session using the `indexer.php` file located in `/magento_root/shell`

> php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url

Comment: This doesn't work if a store view already has a value set to it. How do we regenerate url key for already imported products?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should add to your header `url_key` and `url_path` and set them for each product.

For example, in `url_key` you have "`awesome-product`" and in `url_path` "`awesome-product.html`".

Comment: this is a possibility but they key word he said was "not generating" - had he said "not inserted" or "not imported" I would agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Leave both column (url_key and url_path) empty and upload csv file

Step 2 : After succesful importing csv file, go to System -> Index Management : Click on Select All and click on Submit.

It is very simple way. I tried and got result.